# Can I get hired as a psychology professor if I get a PhD in educational psychology in an education department?

Tags: phd, career-path, psychology, interdisciplinary

I'm interested in educational psychology and learning sciences. However, most educational psychology graduate programs are within the education department, not psychology.

What's the difference between having a PhD in education as opposed to psychology? are there different job prospects? Can I still apply/get hired as a psychology professor if I have an education degree?

I understand answers may vary depending on institutions, but I just want to get an idea.

Comment: Are you interested in getting a PhD in Education, or Educational Psychology?  It's a little unclear from your question.

Comment: There are some related questions for other fields, [Is it possible to become a professor in a field where you don't have a PhD degree?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1131/17254) and [If I want to become a professor, do universities care what field my PhD. is in or just that I have a PhD?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/83253/17254), so this question could be answered as well by someone with experience in the field.